# The type or namespace name 'Dbset<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to use a database in Razor pages. But I get this error when I use command dotnet run: "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Dbset<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
Here is the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace myWebApp.Models
{
    public class ConnectionstringClass: DbContext
    {
        public ConnectionstringClass(DbContextOptions<ConnectionstringClass> options) :base(options)
        {

        }
        public Dbset<Reservation> Reservation {get; set;}
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>().ToTable("Reservation");
            
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the package references:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="3.1.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="4.1.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="5.0.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0"/>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0"/>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Change Dbset to `DbSet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have a typo. Use `DbSet<Reservation>` instead `Dbset<Reservation>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public DbSet<Reservation> Reservation {get; set;}
```

is correct. not

```
public Dbset<Reservation> Reservation {get; set;}
```